# Preventing line breaks between inline-block elements longer than 1 line

Tags: html, css, rendering

A question about formatting HTML 5 inline-block elements:
Two short inline block elements (shorter than one line) neatly wrap together in a single line. If they are longer than one line, there is a line break inserted between them that breaks my layout.
Let's suppose I have HTML like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .my-div {font-size: 0;}
        .my-span { display: inline-block; font-size: 17px; line-height: 1.4em; }
        .a { background-color: Aquamarine; }
        .b { background-color: LightPink; }
        .c { background-color: LightSteelBlue; }
    </style>
</head>
<body><div class="my-div">
        <span class="my-span a">Pellentesque eget dolor eu est finibus tincidunt. Suspendisse dapibus pellentesque mauris ac iaculis. Sed tincidunt rutrum massa quis blandit. Integer rhoncus scelerisque justo eu dapibus. Nam varius eros velit, ut feugiat mauris posuere eu. Aliquam justo nibh, pulvinar vel ipsum sed, euismod placerat nulla.&nbsp;</span><span class="my-span b">Vestibulum blandit erat nec sodales vestibulum. Proin nulla est, feugiat dapibus risus dignissim, egestas pulvinar magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi ut aliquet velit. Donec sodales euismod arcu, eget pulvinar est convallis id. Suspendisse potenti. &nbsp;</span><span class="my-span c">Aenean imperdiet nisi tristique est tincidunt, eget gravida augue porta. Sed mauris risus, consectetur eget convallis sed, maximus eu turpis. Donec ultricies mattis accumsan. Sed posuere ex bibendum, cursus odio sit amet, tincidunt lacus.&nbsp;</span><span class="my-span a">Short text&nbsp;</span><span class="my-span b">More Short text</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome 83.0.4103.106 the HTML looks like this:
[image]
As you can see, the two short text spans at the bottom neatly end up in one line. However, after the longer spans is a line break inserted by the browser. How can I get rid of the extra line break and display the longer spans like the short ones, directly attached to each other, without a line break inserted?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Width of the **inline-block** elements is automatically determined by its contents. As 1st span element is occupying max width of the row, 2nd element is getting wrapped to next line and same with 3rd span as well. Last two elements are in same line because they have the enough space to occupy.

Simple solution of this will be changing **display : inline-block** to **display:inline**

Answer (score 1):

Change the display property of 'my-span' class to inline.

```
display: inline;
```

But line-height will not be applicable.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I have to live with the fact that not all requirements can be fulfilled in this case. :-)

Comment: PS line-height is applicable on inline-block elements as well, height and width are not.